# DISTINCT keyword not working with Image data type in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using `DISTINCT` in SQL query while fetching records from SQL Server table using the below query.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT firstname, lastname, profileImage 
from employee
```

Where **`profileImage`** is of `image` datatype in my table.

**Problem:**

When I try to fetch the data from table using `DISTINCT` in my query gives the below error.

> Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1   The image data type cannot be
>   selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

When I remove `DISTINCT` keyword from my query it works fine.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Ever since the **2005** version of the product, released almost 10 years ago, the following notice has been applied to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187993(v=sql.90).aspx): "ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them"

Comment: @Chris - I understood the error message but I am looking for another way to achieve this. Because I tried to Convert the `profileImage` field to `varchar` but it fails too :(

Comment: Convert to `VARBINARY`

Comment: @Prog - why would you attempt to convert to `varchar` when `image` is for storing *binary* data and the `varbinary` types exist?

Comment: @Prog: Ah, ok. That wasn't clear. The actual question in your question is "Why this happen?" which is pretty clear from the message. What you actually seem to want felt more like a followup bonus to me.

Comment: Since profile images are likely to be distinct in the first place, it seems that the `DISTINCT` keyword would be unrewarding here even if it worked.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I was wondering about the need to distinct a simple table select too, especially in light of the fact that the query apparently works fine without the DISTINCT (though it is unclear if it works fine or if it merely doesn't error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `IMAGE` datatype is fixed and variable-length data type used for
  storing binary data,One of the restrictions of using `IMAGE` data
  type is that columns defined of this data type cannot be used as part
  of a `SELECT` statement that includes the `DISTINCT` clause error message can be encountered using `DISTINCT` in `SELECT`
- `IMAGE` data type can be converted to `VARBINARY` data type. The
  `SELECT` statements earlier which contain the `DISTINCT` clause can
  be rewritten as follows and and avoid the error message:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT CAST([ProfileImage] AS VARBINARY(8000)) AS [ProfileImage]
  FROM [dbo].[table]
  ```

Refer this link:
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-421.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi SDK. While the link may answer the question link only answers are frowned upon. Links are good but also put the key points from that page into your answer. That way if the content moves, or their website explodes your answer is still useful.

Comment: Thanks, I will correct my mistake next time and here is my updated answer

Comment: How do I know which column is an image?